# Is sending query string while using any HTTP method compliant with HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, query-string, standards, http-method

Are all these combinations compliant with `HTTP` standard?

```
GET /entities/?param=value HTTP/1.1
POST /entities/?param=value HTTP/1.1
PUT /entities/?param=value HTTP/1.1
DELETE /entities/?param=value HTTP/1.1
HEAD /entities/?param=value HTTP/1.1
PATCH /entities/?param=value HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in the spec?

Comment: Yes and I didn't find anything restricting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5) (as I read it), they are allowed.

This is how the [Request-Line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) is constructed (like the ones in your example):

> **5.1 Request-Line**
>
> The Request-Line begins with a method token, followed by the
>   Request-URI and the protocol version, and ending with CRLF. The
>   elements are separated by SP characters. No CR or LF is allowed except
>   in the final CRLF sequence.
>
> ```
>     Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
> ```

And then [about Request-URI](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2):

> The `Request-URI` is a Uniform Resource Identifier (section [3.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2)) and
>   identifies the resource upon which to apply the request.

As I see it, the specification makes no restriction on what kind of URIs can be used, and whether they are limited by the use of certain [Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1).